yocto - Why is if statement always false?
I set a debug flag in my local.conf
IS_DEBUG_BUILD = "1"

but a if condition in a Yocto recipe outputs False all the time when I run bitbake -C compile my-recipe
do_install:append() {
    bbwarn ${@d.getVar("IS_DEBUG_BUILD")}
    if [ ${@d.getVar("IS_DEBUG_BUILD")} == '1' ]; then
        bbwarn "True"
    else
        bbwarn "False"
    fi
}

The line bbwarn ${@d.getVar("IS_DEBUG_BUILD")} returns the correct values (0 and 1).
What is wrong here?

" " (double quotes) is for string type, ' ' (single quotes) is for char type, in almost every language... String and char are not the same, therefore an equality check with == will always return false.

Please try this code:
    IS_DEBUG_BUILD_VALUE=${@d.getVar("IS_DEBUG_BUILD")}
    
    if [ "$IS_DEBUG_BUILD_VALUE" = "1" ]; then
        bbwarn "True"
    else
        bbwarn "False"
    fi

The difference is in " " (double quotes) or ' ' (single quotes). They are used for respectively string or char type literals.
In your sample code, you first set the IS_DEBUG_BUILD to "1" (string) and then checked with == but you compared it to '1' (char).
String and char are never the same.

Is the correct syntax = or == ?

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
